# Why does a @ObserveObject reuse the model in NavigationLink , and @StateObject do not?

Tags: swiftui, combine, swiftui-navigationlink

When I run this code in my iPhone Simulator , the ScorePlate will get the reusing(last-time) model after pushed in Navigation.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showRealName = false
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        VStack {
          Button("Toggle Name") {
            showRealName.toggle()
          }
          Text("Current User: \(showRealName ? "Wei Wang" : "onevcat")")
          NavigationLink("Next", destination: ScorePlate().padding(.top, 20))
        }
      }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("Model Created") }
    @Published var score: Int = 0
}

struct ScorePlate: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    @State private var niceScore = false

    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("ScorePlate")
        VStack {
            Button("+1") {
                if model.score > 3 {
                    niceScore = true
                }
                model.score += 1
            }
            Text("Score: \(model.score)")
            Text("Nice? \(niceScore ? "YES" : "NO")")
            ScoreText(model: model).padding(.top, 20)
        }
    }
}

struct ScoreText: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        if model.score > 10 {
            return Text("Fantastic")
        } else if model.score > 3 {
            return Text("Good")
        } else {
            return Text("Ummmm...")
        }
    }
}
```

But if I changed ScorePlate 's model declaration from

`@ObservedObject var model = Model()`

To

`@StateObject var model = Model()`

The reusing will be disappear.

In my understanding , @StateObject will make reusing , and @ObserveObject will make create everytime . But why this make the different in the NavigationLink?

Answer (score 1):

`@StateObject` is init before appear and deinit after disappear. It isn't valid code to init an object with `@ObservedObject` because it has no ownership and it will just get lost the next time the View struct is init. The behaviour you are experiencing is probably related to how `NavigationLink` is holding the `ScorePlate()` value that has the object. If you added a `@State var counter` and a Button that shows the value and increments it - that would cause `ContentView`'s body to be recomputed and a new `NavigationLink` and `ScorePlate` to be created and its previous `ObservedObject` will probably be lost.

If you want it to always be reused then move the `StateObject` up, into `ContentView` and pass it into `ScorePlate`. We always place `@State` and `@StateObject` in the highest common parent of where it is needed. Since you aren't doing anything that needs an async lifetime you could just use a `@State` by the way, use a struct to group vars or have testable logic in mutating funcs.

Comment: Thanks @malhal , So this confusing behaviour seems caused by the NavigationLink, when poped by NavigationLink ,the destinationView will not be released, so the ObservedObject will remain exist . But the StateObject will be released , because the destinationView's willDisappear will be called